# Annotate method in django

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem with annotate. I want to display records from my class Kategorie in the main html file. I used the annotate method to take the query from db. I used in the second class Firmy the ForeignKey to class Kategorie. Now I dont know how to display for example how many websites added in the class Firmy are in the for example in category Business. Now I have something like: "Business (2)(3)(4)" when I used annotate with count by id. This is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Kategorie(models.Model):
    glowna = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Kategoria')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Kategoria'
        verbose_name_plural='Kategorie'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.glowna


class Witryna(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(default="", max_length=150, verbose_name = 'Nazwa strony')
    adres_www = models.CharField(max_length=70, verbose_name='Adres www')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Przyjazny adres url')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Adres e-mail')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=3000, verbose_name='Opis strony')
    kategoria = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name='Kategoria')
    data_publikacji = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data publikacji')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Strona www'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Strony www'

    def publikacja(self):
        self.data_publikacji=timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa
```

And some part from **views.py**

```
from django.db.models import Count

    wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('Witryna'))
```

So what kind of method or tags I have to use to display for example:

```
Business(34)
Industry(21)
Health Care(11)
```

where the name od category is field from class Kategorie and integer is a result from query to database how many websites are in for example Business category?

My **html** file is:

```
{%  for kategoria in kategorie %}
<table>
<tr>
<td>

<li><a href="{% url 'detale_kat' slug_kat=kategoria.slug_kat %}">{{ kategoria.glowna|linebreaksbr }} </a></li>
{% for wpis in wpisy_kat %}
{{ wpis }} ({{ cat.cnt_witryna }})
{% endfor %}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
{%  endfor %}
```

and the main **html** file:

```
{% include 'firmy/header.html' %}
<html>
<body>
<p>
<center>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="link1.html">Strona główna</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2.html">Jak dodać stronę</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3.html">Regulamin</a></li>
    <li><a href="link4.html">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
</center>
<div class="glowna">
    <div class="lewe_menu">

    <h3><center>Ostatnio dodane</center></h3>

    {%include 'firmy/widok_strony.html'%}
    </div>
    <div class="srodek">

        <h3><center>Kategorie</center></h3>
        <center>{%include 'firmy/widok_kategorii.html'%} </center>
    </div>
    <div class="prawe_menu">

    <h3><center>Reklama</center></h3>
    <center>Tutaj wpisz kod reklamy </center>
    </div>
    {% include 'firmy/footer.html' %}
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**view.py** file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Witryna, Kategorie
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Count


def widok_strony(request):
    firmy = Witryna.objects.filter(data_publikacji__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('data_publikacji')
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_strony.html', {'firmy': firmy})

def widok_kategorii(request):
    kategorie = Kategorie.objects.all()
    wpisy_kat = Witryna.objects.annotate(cnt_kategoria=Count('kategoria'))
    return render(request, 'firmy/widok_kategorii.html', {'kategorie': kategorie, 'wpisy_kat': wpisy_kat,})

def index(request):
    firmy = Witryna.objects.filter(data_publikacji__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('data_publikacji')
    kategorie = Kategorie.objects.order_by('glowna')
    wpisy_kat = Witryna.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('kategoria'))
    return render(request, 'firmy/index.html', {'kategorie': kategorie, 'wpisy_kat': wpisy_kat, 'firmy': firmy})

def detale_strony(request, slug):
    det_wpisu = get_object_or_404(Witryna, slug=slug)
    firmy = Witryna.objects.filter(data_publikacji__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('data_publikacji')
    return render(request, 'firmy/detale_strony.html', {'det_wpisu': det_wpisu, 'firmy': firmy})

def detale_kat(request, slug_kat):
    det_kategorii = get_object_or_404(Kategorie, slug_kat=slug_kat)
    firmy = Witryna.objects.filter(data_publikacji__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('data_publikacji')
    return render(request, 'firmy/detale_kat.html', {'det_kategorii': det_kategorii, 'firmy': firmy})
```

Comment: please update your question with the html template you are using (you can delete the screenshot, it's not helping in this case)

Comment: the html files were attached

Comment: be careful, in `{{ wpis }} ({{ cat.cnt_witryna }})` : replace `cat` by `wpis`, then you are mixing two for loops, the annotate method already gives you  the list of categories, you should try with only mine to check, and then add the `<a>` tag with `wpis.slug_kat` (no need to use a table)

Comment: Yop I changed on {{wpis.cnt.witryna}} and the result is for example: Aktualności i media (1)(1)(1). When I enter in to the category in every category i have this same pages not only for example: google.com in category Websites.

Comment: please add also the code of view that renders this html, i cannot understand why it's listing sites instead of categories

Comment: Ok the views.py was attached.

Comment: why did you reverse your first test ? You were closer in your question .. check my edit

Comment: Ok I wilk check this solution at the evening because now I have to pause my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view needs to return something like :

```
wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('witryna'))
return render(request, 'app/template.html', {'wpisy_kat': wpisy_kat})
```

**template.html :**

```
<ul>
{% for cat in wpisy_kat %}

    <li>{{ cat }} ({{ cat.cnt_witryna }})</li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

EDIT :

You can add sorting or filtering to the annotate query, no need to pass 2 parameters from the view, and no need to perform to for/loops :

replace the query in the view :

```
wpisy_kat = Kategorie.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('witryna')).order_by('glowna')
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<ul>
{% for cat in wpisy_kat %}

    <li><a href="{% url 'detale_kat' slug_kat=cat.slug_kat %}">{{ cat }} ({{ cat.cnt_witryna }}) </a></li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: It's returned me all pages what I have in Database without splited on categories.

Comment: @killerbees  `Kategorie.objects.annotate(cnt_witryna=Count('witryna'))` this line should list all the categories and adds the number of associated pages (`witryna` in lowercase), have you check this within the shell ?

Comment: I wrote the post aswer so my problem is above that comments

Comment: @killerbees ok, i saw the screenshot, the categories are in blue ? what are the names listed in black ? (you should better update your post than post an answer like this)

Comment: Yes categories what were added in Kategorie class are in blue colour. The black colored like:"Bardzo fajna strona internetowa" and the rests, are the titles from websites added in Witryna class. I want to build a app like Web directory for example: http://www.bazastron.com.pl/ when You visit that website, On this website You will see the central <div> with categories and numer of pages in category.

Comment: Great it's display me correctly how many websites are in the categories but its counted 6 times this same.

Comment: @killerbees this seems to be linked to the database content, not the annotate rendering, you should check it in the admin section

Comment: PRMoureu now the categories are display very well. The problem is with the linking, thats why the categories are showing 6 or more times. When I have for example Category: Aktualności i Media, I have the detail view for Aktualności i Media in every record of Category for the time when is the last record of database the procedure starts once again for the second record of db. Sorry for the confusing :)

Comment: @killerbees, you should create another question to explain what's wrong, you will have more room to show the details, sorry i didn't quite understand the issue

Comment: Ok I will create a new question